Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath
I'm trying to run my first hibernate program on eclipse tomcat version-10 but it is showing following error.I have already added jar files from lib in module path as well as all the required dependencies in POM.xml file still it is showing error.Please help.
Apr 19, 2024 6:42:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null  at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:134)     at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)  at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)    at org.udemy.App.main(App.java:11) Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.  - with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)     at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:123)     ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)  at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)   at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)     ... 9 more 

Here is POM.xml file-
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>1</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hibernate-1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.release>18</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hibernate-1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>

Here is App.java
package org.udemy;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.udemy.entity.users;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(users.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            users user=new  users("username","email");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction();
            System.out.println("Row added");
            
            
        }finally {
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}

Here ishibernate.cfg.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Version 8 MySQL hiberante-cfg.xml example for Hibernate 5 -->
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <!-- property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>
    <!--property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property-->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- mapping class="com.mcnz.jpa.examples.Player" / -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

users.java
package org.udemy.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name="users")
public class users {
    int user_id;
    String username,email;
    
    
    public users(String username, String email) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }   
}


I have already used all the dependencies that are suggested in other related posts but still getting the same error.
